# RStudio environment pane does not show knitr variables

Tags: r, knitr

I have a very simple knitr Rnw script. When I run it in RStudio, the Environment Pane shows that the global environment is empty although the script compiles into pdf correctly, and the variable is evaluated correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<settings, echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
a<-1+10
@

The outcome is equal to \Sexpr{a}.

\end{document}
```

This worked fine always until recently. I wonder whether this has to do with some RStudio settings or knitr options. Variables in a regular R script show up fine in the environment pane. For more complex knitr projects, being able to look at the variables can make work much much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you knit a document by clicking `knit` in RStudio, it is run in a separate R process, and the variables are deleted when done.  Your code chunks won't be able to see variables in your environment, and those variables won't get modified.

There are ways to run in your current process:  run each chunk as code, or run `rmarkdown::render("somefilename.Rmd")` in your main process.  Then your document can see your current workspace and make modifications there.

For debugging, the 2nd approach is convenient, but for reproducibility of the final result, you should run the separate R process.

Comment: This did not do it for me. Still not showing anything in the environment. But you provided the correct answer to another question - not sure why I had not found that one before. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this is what worked for me. Instead of clicking on "Compile pdf" button in RStudio, I ran the following in the console:

```
knitr::knit2pdf("file.Rnw", envir = globalenv())
```

This had been recommended here:
[knitr: why does nothing appear in the "environment" panel when I compile my .Rnw file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55867995/knitr-why-does-nothing-appear-in-the-environment-panel-when-i-compile-my-rnw?rq=1)